# Is it legal to drink your own alcohol onboard a plane over international waters?

Tags: air-travel, legal, alcohol, international-waters

A debate was ensuing at work about consuming your own booze onboard a plane.

[The FAA can fine you several thousand dollars in the US](http://www.flask.com/can-i-bring-my-own-alcohol-on-an-airplane/#.U5aI1Sjm7pU) if you did this, so naturally this led to people theorising ways around this.

The top theory was that once you were over international waters, it would be permitted.  I'm fairly sure you come under the laws of the company operating the aircraft, but don't have evidence for it.

So - is it legal to consume your own alcohol onboard over international waters?

Comment: Strange, that's the first time I even hear that you might not be allowed to do so. Obviously, if the airline does not permit to drink alcohol on their flights, e.g. Air India, then you shouldn't do that. But other airlines, e.g. Swiss even gives you alcohol for free on their flights, so then I should be able to also bring my own alcohol. At least I always thought that way.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I recently flew Air India, I'm pretty sure they were serving complimentary alcohol on their flights. Their website seems to say the same as well - http://www.airindia.com/economy-class.htm

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Are you talking about Domestic flights though? There I believe it's just a matter of economy rather than law, also many airlines don't serve alcohol in domestic flights - http://maphappy.org/2012/07/wine-the-ultimate-list-of-airlines-that-serve-free-alcohol/

Comment: @AdityaSomani Yes, it was a domestic flight. I thought it's because of religious reasons or things like that.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Although there are a good amount of Muslims in India, Hinduism does not explicitly forbid consumption of alcohol so certainly it's not because of religious reasons. :)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Apparently Swiss along with almost every other airline does not allow this _in official capacity atleast_. You could probably get away with it but it's definitely not legal in most airlines.

Comment: I'd have thought that if it were a FAA rule, it would apply at all times to a US airline, and in US airspace for a non-US airline (with their home/own rules after that)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException OP states drinking your OWN alcohol. Not drinking alcohol all together. So with some companies that would mean having to buy stuff, while you are already carrying your own.

Comment: @nl-x I know. What made you think that I might have missed that?

Comment: Laws of the flag country apply when you are in a vehicle (airplane or ship) above or in international waters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends primarily on the airline policy. The only airline I believe is **Royal Brunei Airlines** which allows consumption of personal alcohol on-board because it does not serve any on the aircraft.

**Any airline which serves alcohol on-board typically does not allow consumption of personal alcohol.** I suspect the reason for this is to maintain decorum during the flight and prevent people from drinking too much which would compromise the safety of other passengers including the intoxicated person in tense situations.

As mentioned in the question, the [FAA](http://www.airweb.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/4169CCE6717F88B386256BC9004338B6?OpenDocument&Highlight=121.575) prohibits alcohol which is not served by the certificate holder operating the aircraft. So, this rules out the United States.

---

Most airlines don't provide any specific information about it in their **General Conditions of International Carriage for Passenger and Baggage**. If you want to look up for a specific airline, the **Conduct Aboard the Aircraft (Article 11,12 or 15 typically)** can provide information regarding the same.

---

One example we can talk about is airlines which [do not serve alcohol](http://getawaytips.azcentral.com/airlines-not-serve-alcohol-3398.html) on their flights:

- [Saudi Arabian Airlines (Saudia)](http://stageenv.saudiairlines.com/saudia/Travel/Terms+&+Conditions/Saudi+Airlines+Terms,+Conditions,+Passenger+Advice,+etc...) does not allow it in any form

  > Saudi Arabian Airlines does not serve or permit passengers to carry or
  >   drink alcoholic beverages on its flights.
- [Royal Brunei Airlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Brunei_Airlines#In-flight_service_and_awards) doesn't serve alcohol but allows you to carry some ***and consume on board*** (does not specify domestic or international waters). It also does not mention anything regarding this in their [Carriage Conditions](http://www.flyroyalbrunei.com/rba/carriage-conditions.php#conduct).
- [Pakistan International Airlines](http://www.piac.com.pk/pia_policynterms/coc.pdf) does not allow it in any form

  > You are not allowed to consume alcohol aboard an aircraft (whether
  >   purchased as duty free or otherwise obtained)

---

Another example we must talk about is European airlines which do serve alcohol:

- [Swiss Airways](http://www.swiss.com/ch/EN/terms-conditions/conditions-of-carriage/article-11) serves alcohol but does not allow passengers to consume their own alcohol.

  > It is forbidden to consume any alcohol which you may have personally
  >   brought on board.
- [Condor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condor_Flugdienst) also serves alcohol but [does not allow personal alcohol](http://www.condor.com/eu/flight-info/on-board/food-and-beverages.jsp).

  > Passengers are not allowed to consume the alcoholic beverages they
  >   bring on board during the flight, including duty-free items purchased
  >   at the airport or on the plane.
- [KLM](http://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/customer_support/booking_conditions_carriage/article_11_to_15.htm) follows the same policy as the others

  > 15.4  The Carrier may limit or prohibit the consumption of alcohol on board the aircraft. Consumption of any alcoholic beverages carried
  >   into the aircraft by Passengers or consumption of any duty free
  >   product bought on board the aircraft is prohibited.
- So does [Virgin Atlantic](http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/gb/en/travel-information/customer-service/conditions-of-carriage/article-11.html)

  > For safety reasons, consumption of alcohol by passengers is restricted
  >   to alcohol served by us, with the result that alcohol purchased by
  >   passengers (whether as duty free purchases at airports or aboard
  >   aircraft or other purchases) cannot be consumed aboard our aircraft.

---

Now, airlines in Asia which also serve alcohol:

- [Air India](http://home.airindia.in/terms.htm) doesn't say it specifically but it implies that personal alcohol consumption is not allowed

  > Passengers are also permitted to consume their own snacks and
  >   non-alcoholic drinks on board.
- [China Eastern](http://us.ceair.com/muovc/main/en_US/Static_pages/GeneralConditions.html#15) says it quite specifically

  > Except for the alcoholic drinks provided by CEAIR flights, Passengers
  >   shall not have any other alcoholic drinks on board the aircraft.
- [Ukraine International Airlines](http://www.flyuia.com/eng/information-and-services/GENERAL-CONDITIONS-OF-CARRIAGE.html) does not either

  > Drinking of any alcoholic drinks on board an aircraft is permitted
  >   only in amounts offered by the airline.
- [Gulf Air](http://www.gulfair.com/English/aboutgulfair/Pages/GeneralConditions.aspx) has the same policy as the others

  > You are not allowed to consume alcohol aboard an aircraft (whether
  >   purchased as duty free from us or someone else or otherwise obtained)
  >   unless it has been served to you by us. We have the right, at any time
  >   and for any reason, to refuse to serve you alcohol or to withdraw
  >   alcohol which has been served to you.

Comment: So then Saudi Arabian would NOT be a valid answer, as I'm looking for one that says you CAN over international waters :/

Comment: @MarkMayo Royal Brunei does! Bear with me man!

Comment: @MarkMayo Done! Apparently, Royal Brunei is the _only_ one which allows it. All the others or any other airlines which serve alcohol prohibits BYO alcohol on flights.